# python, delete common characters from two strings

Tags: python, string

Given two strings suppose stringA and stringB (len(stringA)>len(stringB)), how do i remove all characters from stringA which are present in stringB? Assume that all characters in stringB are present in stringA

Here is what i tried:

```
a=input()
b=input()

for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] not in a:
        a.remove(b[i])
```

I expected it to remove characters from A, but resulting in an error, I am a beginner in python and i havent a clue which other method or approach i should use here

Comment: I think strings in Python are immutable - you cannot change them. Better would be to first convert them to list, tuple or set so that  you can use something set difference operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `set` of B for efficiency and loop over all characters of A with a list comprehension to filter and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them:

```
s = set(B)
out = ''.join([c for c in A if not c in s])
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know I could pass strings to set() ig it reduces the number of iterations and removes the duplicate iterations

Answer (score 1):

```
stringA = input()
stringB = input()

for char in stringB:
    stringA = stringA.replace(char, "")

print(stringA)
```

Comment: seems relatively easy compared to other solutions thanks dude it compiles

Comment: It's easy but also inefficient, it needs to read again the full string for each character to remove.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
new_s1 = ""
new_s2 = ""
for char in s1:
    if char not in s2:
        new_s1 += char

for char in s2:
    if char not in s1:
        new_s2 += char

print(new_s1)  
print(new_s2)
```

Comment: thanks, this is quite interesting, but ig if there was memory or time constraint it would not be optimal

Answer (score 0):

`str` object has no method called `remove`. You have to use sth like `replace`  or use `set` for efficiency:

```py
out = "".join(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```

Note that this will not necessarily maintain order of the characters of A.

Comment: This will not necessarily maintain order of the characters of A

Comment: Yeah I just assumed that OP doesn't care about order. I added you comment to answer. tnx @mozway

Comment: yeah i forgot to mention it, order was important in my case